# How to echo query result using PHP mysql (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This may seem silly, but I can't figure out how to do this simple thing in spite of much googling.

I have the fully functional PHP script that queries a mysql database to check for a boolean value.  My script contains the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT truefalse FROM mydb WHERE bilbobaggins=:bilbobaggins";

$query = $db->prepare($sql);

try {

$query->execute(array(

        ':bilbobaggins' => $bilbobaggins

));

} catch (Exception $e) {

echo "Query failed. " . ($e->getMessage());
$db = null;
die;

}
```

All I'm trying to do is have the result of the query echo back from the script, such that for example, if I put

```
http://www.myurl.com/myscript.php?bilbobaggins=user32984329842
```

into a browser, it will return either a 1 or a 0 in text format.

I suspect I need to change the line:

```
$query->execute(array(
```

To something like:

```
print $query->execute(array(
```

But that does not work.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: We'll need to see more code than that, as well as an explanation of exactly what is or is not working.

Comment: You need to fetch the result.

Comment: Why try and catch the exception, and not let it fail naturally?

Comment: In my arrays fed to PDO, I always use `'key' => $key` and never `':key' => $key`, but think both might work.

Comment: I editted the original post to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo $row['truefalse'];
}
```

:)

Comment: This code works fine, I don't understand the downvotes. However the OP will also need to escape `key` with backquotes because it is a reserved word in MySQL. ``$sql = "SELECT truefalse FROM mydb WHERE `key`=:key";``

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT truefalse FROM mydb WHERE `key`=:key";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('key' => $key));
header('Content-Type: text/plain;');
echo($stmt->fetchColumn());
```

Comment: `key` is a reserved word in MySQL. You'll need to escape it with backquotes. ``$sql = "SELECT truefalse FROM mydb WHERE `key`=:key";``